# UICollectionview cell size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I want to be able to stretch the cell full window width, but retain the actual cell height.  Is there a better way to do this then instantiating a NIB object and getting the height.  This collection will eventually consist of about 20+ different types of cell designs.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width
    //let sizingCell = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! CustomCell

    //return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize, height:sizingCell.frame.height)
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize, height: 70)
  }
```

Comment: If the heights of your custom cells are constant you might add static method to your custom cell class as: `static var myCustomCellHeight: CGFloat { return 70 }`

Comment: Doesn't that still involve me creating a cell object in "sizeForItemAt" and grabbing the height?

Comment: No, static functions are called on the class itself, instead of on instances.

Comment: I see what you are getting at.  That should work.  Its too bad this ca not be done dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

this is titlt

you must implement     ***UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout***

and then you can edit the cell size

ps: better use

> collectionView.bounds.size.width

to get the width of collectionView

Comment: not looking to get the width.  I want to reuse the actual cell height.  I am already implementing UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout as I am trying to accomplish this in "sizeForItemAt"

Comment: have you created from storyboard or in code, the collectionView?

Comment: its created in Storyboard.  The cells are XIBs.